# Best practice for multi-language mails?

Tags: email, language, multilingual

I have to design an email invitation for a customer. The customer offers a service for companies to communicate with their suppliers. So the companies enter the email addresses of their suppliers, and these are invited to create an account.
Since I only have the addresses, I have no idea what language the invited person speaks. I think I'll have to include the text in several languages in the email or provide links "read in English", "lea en Español", "auf Deutsch lesen" and so on.

Any better ideas? Do you know examples of such emails that can be an inspiration?

Comment: Do you know how many languages do you expect to have in a mail? If it is only two, a common approach is to add a line in the beginning saying something like "For English, scroll to the bottom".

Comment: Are you planning to allow for both plain text and HTML versions? Links would work only in HTML. However, a good practice is to allow fallback to plain text. An alternative would be the commonly encountered "Read contents in website" link.

Answer (score 1):

I would have the email in the main language, let's say English, and then on the side have a column that says "view email in other languages" and you click the preferred language that takes you to a website with translated version.

Answer (score 0):

We've a similar challenge (companies which can invite their subcontractors on our B2B platform). So what we design about it so far is:

Since the company knows who is invited, we propose it to select the language after filling in the subcontrator's email.

If not, the email will be sent in 2 languages, first in the company's language (german for example) and second always in english.

You must limit the number of languages in your email. If not, the user'll no more read it.